Why can't halfword-size data be placed on address 4x+1?
I've read several articles about data alignment and padding, and all of them tell me that the aim of alignment & padding is facilitating data access from memory(or cache).
Like an integer, which is 4-byte size, should be put on addresses of 4n, otherwise processor would need to fetch an integer using two clock cycle. I agree with this.
However, it forces a halfword data(like short int) to be put on 2n addresses. But since the aim is to use minimal clock cycle reading the data, I think we can also place short integers on addresses of 4n+1, as short integer placed at these addresses are all inside one word(in a 32-bit machine), which means we can also fetch them using only one clock cycle.
As to double which is 8 bytes, I think if we put them on addresses of 4n, we can also fetch them by only two clock cycle. However, the rule forces them to be put on 8n addresses.

Maybe you could make that work with a single halfword object, but what about an array?

Note that you're describing a very simplistic model for a memory bus, which doesn't really describe any server or desktop computer made in the last 30 years.  Nowadays the basic unit transferred to and from memory is a cache line which is typically 64 bytes.  Some machines (not all) will handle misaligned data without penalty so long as it fits within a cache line, but usually there is a penalty for crossing a cache line boundary.  There is a larger penalty for crossing a page boundary (4k typically) which can be hundreds of clock cycles.

That is because most of the CPU designs that suggest this requirement for compiler alignment of structures have older chip versions that actually have a 16 bit memory interface, so on those older hardware versions, reading or writing a 2 byte value at address 4n+1 will require two memory cycles, one for the 16 bits at 4n, then the 16 bits at 4n+2 .  Even if the current CPU hardware design could have a fast path for the 4n+1 case, it would be extra transistors for a case that existing programs rarely use anyway, so they don't waste the square nanometers.
As the compilers evolve with the CPU family, compatibility with programs compiled under the rule by the previous compiler version requires the next compiler version to keep the rule for API compatibility, then again and again for every future version and every compatible compiler.
Important examples are the PDP-11 to VAX evolution (with 9 bit bytes and 18 bit shorts), the x86 evolution (from the 8086 16 bit bus and the IBM PC AT expansion slots to the AMD64 family with their 128 bit DRAM interfaces for pairs of DDRx RAM sticks), the 68000 CPU family (the old 16 bit chips were used in machines like the older Macintosh machines, the full 32 bit machines in later ones) etc. etc.

Your question is based on some very simplistic assumptions.  But let's suppose, for the sake of argument, that you do have a machine where a halfword at a 4n+1 address can be accessed without penalty.
Languages and toolchains typically define alignment rules very simply, via a single power of 2 associated with a given type.  Saying "halfwords require 2-byte alignment" is very simple and can be expressed with something like alignof(halfword) == 2.  Rules like "you can place it on address 4n, 4n+1, 4n+2, but not 4n+3" are harder to express within a system, and require you to add complexity.
The simple rule has the other advantage that it can be applied not only to single objects, but also to arrays without change.  If you place a halfword on a 2-byte boundary, and it happens to be the first element of an array, then the next element is automatically also properly aligned, without needing to insert any padding in between.  But your 4n+1 rule can only be applied to a standalone halfword object, not to an array; if you place the first element of an array on 4n+1, then the next element is on 4n+3 which is not good.  Or else you need to insert padding, which wastes memory and greatly complicates address calculations (quick, how do you find the address of element 100?).  So now you need a separate rule for arrays than for single objects, which adds complexity.
Finally, it doesn't gain much.  If all the objects in your program are halfword or larger, then 2-byte alignment is automatic and free.  The only time when you don't automatically have alignment is when you mix in single-byte objects.  The extra padding bytes typically don't add up to any significant amount of memory usage; and if they do, you can usually avoid this just by rearranging them, to clump the single-byte objects together.  Then you only potentially need a padding byte at the end of each clump.
